# How to connect to GCP Cloud SQL using CLoud IAM user

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The first answer here is a guide on how to connect to your Cloud SQL database using a Cloud SQL IAM User.

[Follow these steps to create a user first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70866022/how-to-create-gcp-cloud-sql-iam-users/70866023#70866023)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install Google Cloud SDK for your local machine.
   https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install
2. Run `gcloud` in any terminal to authenticate your Google Cloud Platform User on your system.

   - `gcloud init`
3. Download Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy for your operating system.  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy

   - **Windows**: Just Download
   - **MacOS**: `curl -o cloud_sql_proxy https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.darwin.amd64`
   - **MacOS**: `chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy`
4. Run the proxy from the downloaded directory to start. Keep it running for the duration you want to be connected. Choose a TCP port that is unused on your system. the `-instances` field is your instance connection name, on the instance overview page

   - **Windows**: `.\cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="project:region:db-instance"=tcp:5432 -enable_iam_login`
   - **MacOS Silicon**: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` - needed to run software for older cpus
   - **MacOS Silicon**: `arch -x86_64 zsh` - opens up a terminal which can run the software
   - **MacOS & MacOS Silicon**: `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="project:region:db-instance"=tcp:5432 -enable_iam_login`
5. The service is now running and allows connection to the database. This includes any coded packages and modules from your favourite language, also applications like PgAdmin, DataGrip, Jetbrains Database Navigator and Chrome Database explorers to connect. Set connection settings to

   - **Host**: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
   - **User**: `username@email.com`
   - **Pasword**: `yourGCPpassword`

---

Other Resources

- [Quickstart for using the Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart-proxy-test)
- [MacOS running arch64 processes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable)
- [Debugging Connection Issues](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/debugging-connectivity)